# Integrate The Event calendar in Child Page of WordPress website

Tags: wordpress

I am using The Events calendar By Modern Tribe, Inc. Its a wonderful plugin for managing events.

But I am having issue displaying the event calendar in child pages.
I have a page named Sports and under sports I have child page called events.

Now I want to show the event calendar under child "event" page of sports parent
page. There is a setting in plugin where we can only assign parent page slug but not child page slug.

Please suggest me any suitable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shortcode [tribe_events] on the child page.